# Session Token Transmission

Tags: session, session-state

There is a requirement for my web application regarding sessions. Points are below:-

1. Session Ids must be randomly generated.
2. Session Ids must be unpredictable.
3. The size of session Id should be large enough to ensure that it is not vulnerable to a brute force attack.
4. The character set should be complex, i.e. Make use of special character.
5. A length of 50 random characters is advised.

Comment: .....aaaaaaand your question is?

Comment: my question is how to accomplish and ensure those points.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the answer to all those points is: use a good random number generator. Your system or platform should have some form of good PRNG to offer; on UNIX that's `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`, on Windows it's its build-in crypto API. Your language of choice likely offers a wrapper API around those. Simply suck a number of random bytes out of that PRNG. If it's any good, those bytes will be random and unpredictable. The length is entirely up to you, just read enough data from the PRNG. The character set will be more than complex enough, since you'll receive raw bytes; you'll in fact have to "dumb them down" into the ASCII character set, for example by base 64 encoding them.